# Datasource for Mailmerge in Word2010 lost if called from Access-VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, office-2010, mailmerge, word-2010

I have a problem migrating from Office2007 to Office2010 (and WXP -> W7). I'm using an Access program to create a CSV file that is used as a datasource for mailmerging. After creating the CSV my program creates a new word document from a template file. The template is setup to use the created CSV file as data source. The CSV is created in the same path all the time.

I'm using the following code

```
Set doc = msWord.Documents.Add(Template:=templatename)
```

`msWord` obviously is my word application reference, and `templatename` is the full path to my template.

This worked fine with Windows XP and Office 2007. It does NOT work with W7 and Office 2010. My template still creates a new document and it opens, but it is no longer a mail merge main document.

Even stranger, if i create a new document simply by double clicking my template, everything works.

The folder the template is in is a trusted folder for Word as well as for Access. Are there any changes in Office2010, perhaps some security settings? Does anyone know how to fix it? Or at least has some hints where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Have you implemented the Windows registry described in this article

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/825765

for Word 2010 as well as Word 2007?